# Parse "m/%d/%Y %H:%M" form of datetime in R

Tags: r, lubridate

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(time = structure(1:10, .Label = c("1/1/2001 0:00", 
"1/1/2001 1:00", "1/1/2001 2:00", "1/1/2001 3:00", "1/1/2001 4:00", 
"1/1/2001 5:00", "1/1/2001 6:00", "1/1/2001 7:00", "1/1/2001 8:00", 
"1/1/2001 9:00"), class = "factor"), values = c(19.94, 19.94, 
12.92, 15.08, 12.02, 12.02, 12.02, 12.92, 12.92, 8.96)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

For `time` column, it represent: `m/%d/%Y %H:%M`, but when I parse them with following code, both of code return `time` to `NA`.

```
df$time <- strptime(df$time, format="m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df$time <- as.Date(df$time, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df$time
```

Out:

```
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

Finally, I need to split `time` column into columns of `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour` and `minutes`.

Someone could help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just forgot a `%` in the beginning of your format string, this should work:

```
strptime(df$time, format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
```

Comment: Thanks, any ideas how to split week of day from it?

Comment: Either use Format with just `"%a"` as format or use the `wday` function from the `lubridate` package.

Answer (score 1):

There are functions in `lubridate` which allows to extract the values you want from `POSIXct` objects.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df %>%
  mutate(time = mdy_hm(time), 
         year = year(time), 
         month = month(time), 
         day = day(time), 
         hour = hour(time), 
         minute = minute(time), 
         weekday = wday(time))


#                  time values year month day hour minute weekday
#1  2001-01-01 00:00:00  19.94 2001     1   1    0      0       2
#2  2001-01-01 01:00:00  19.94 2001     1   1    1      0       2
#3  2001-01-01 02:00:00  12.92 2001     1   1    2      0       2
#4  2001-01-01 03:00:00  15.08 2001     1   1    3      0       2
#5  2001-01-01 04:00:00  12.02 2001     1   1    4      0       2
#6  2001-01-01 05:00:00  12.02 2001     1   1    5      0       2
#7  2001-01-01 06:00:00  12.02 2001     1   1    6      0       2
#8  2001-01-01 07:00:00  12.92 2001     1   1    7      0       2
#9  2001-01-01 08:00:00  12.92 2001     1   1    8      0       2
#10 2001-01-01 09:00:00   8.96 2001     1   1    9      0       2
```

Comment: Thanks, any ideas how to split week of day from it?

Comment: @ahbon You can use `wday` function for it. See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works:

```
df$time <- lubridate::mdy_hm(df$time)

df %>%
  separate(time, into = c('year', 'month', 'day', 'hour'))
```